# MOSS 2007, localize site?

Tags: localization

I have MOSS 2007, and I'd like to make it localizable.

Some toolbox control with "English"/"other language", like on many ASP.NET sites. As I understand, in ASP.NET it is possible via master pages technology.

As I understand, I can use language packs and "Variations" in MOSS menu.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/about-source-variations-HA010121299.aspx?CTT=3

But what will I get in result - will I have two different pages, where I can put content in different languages, or it will be only system messages localized(by example "Site actions", "Create", etc.)?

Do You have some links where I can see localized SharePoint sites in the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll get is two different pages where the system provided text will be automatically localised to each of the locales/languages and the user provided content will need to be manually translated.

Variations will ONLY work for publishing sites and then only for items in the Pages library.

I really like the overview that Gary Lapointe provides in [this pdf](http://www.thelapointes.com/blog/presentations/sptechcon/Variations_and_the_MUI_in_SharePoint2010.pdf) it's specific to 2010 but many of the concepts carry back to MOSS.

Comment: Hi GavinB!

Thank You for Your response!

Can Ypu explain please what You mean saying "Variations will ONLY work for publishing sites" - does it mean it works only for sites created from Publishing template, or You mean sites publishaed in internet, with forms authentication?

So as i'm understanding - sharepoint localization is not quite standard task as for classic ASP.NET site?

Comment: No problem, in this case it does mean specifically only sites that have been created using the Publishing templates.